# How can I get the order id of a woocommerce order to use in a function in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

How can I get the order id of a woocommerce order to be used in a function in functions.php?

I would like to be able to check the id of the order(s) when at:

the woocommerce my account page (for each order):
http://example.com/my-account

and

the woocommerce checkout page (for the current order):
http://example.com/checkout/order-pay/210?pay_for_order=true&key=order_53df9a0e8116a

I know that on the check out page, the order id can be accessed through $order->id; in the form-pay.php template (located at plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-pay.php) I would like to be able to do the same from inside my theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Try `var_dump($GLOBALS)` to see if this ID is available somewhere in the global scope. Otherwise, check `$_POST` and `$_GET`

Comment: If the order hasn't been placed yet you can't get the order_id because it doesn't exist yet. You can get the order number immediately after the checkout is finished by using the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` action.

Comment: the order id does exist in this case because they're being created using the "add order" feature of oscommerce. When you create the order, customers can click a "pay" button when they're in the "my account" section. In the example above, 210 is the order number/post id for the order.

Comment: $_POST is empty, and $_GET doesn't have it. var_dump($GLOBALS) has a massive amount of data to sort through. For some reason I wasn't able to make var_dump readable with echo '<pre>'.var_dump($GLOBALS).'</pre>';

Comment: get_query_var('order-pay'); worked, thanks to this.lau_'s suggestion.

Comment: noticed i said oscommerce above, meant to write woocommerce (can't edit the comment anymore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:
`get_query_var('order-pay');`

I found this by looking through `var_dump($GLOBALS)` - thanks to **this.lau_'s** suggestion

Comment: I was able to see order-pay in var_dump($GLOBALS), but when I added $order_id = get_query_var('order-pay'), the $order_id shows null. 
Is there anyother way to get order ID?